# Can the dimension of Hom space between vector bundles on an algebraic curve predicted by Riemann-Roch type formula be the minimal possible?

Tags: vector-bundles, algebraic-curves, grothendieck-riemann-roch

Let us study vector bundles $E$ and $F$ on a smooth projective curve $C$. There is a Riemann-Roch type formula for the Euler characteristic $\chi(E,F)=dim\, Hom(E,F)-dim\, Ext^1(E,F)$ in terms of degrees $d(E),d(F)$, ranks $r(E),r(F)$ and the genus $g$ of $C$. Assume that this formula gives a non-positive number (this is equivalent to $\mu(F)-\mu(E)\le g-1$).

Is it true that for generic $E$ and $F$ with such ranks and degrees one has $Hom(E,F)=0$? Or is it true at least for some $E,F$?

(This is clearly true for line bundles, but I failed to answer the question for arbitrary vector bundles after several days of thinking)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, it is positive. 
The statement is equivalent to a theorem of Hirschowitz, see Th. 1.2 in arXiv:alg-geom/9710019v2.

Comment: The paper you mention is published: B. Russo, M. Teixidor, 
*On a conjecture of Lange*, 
J. Algebraic Geom. 8 (1999), no. 3, 483–496.